# Filtering pandas dataframe by difference of adjacent rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe indexed by datetime. I want to filter out rows based on the difference between their index and the index of the previous row.

So, if my criteria is "remove all rows that are over one hour late than the previous row", the second row in the example below should be removed:

```
2005-07-15 17:00:00  
2005-07-17 18:00:00
```

While in the following case, both rows stay:

```
2005-07-17 23:00:00  
2005-07-18 00:00:00
```

Comment: what should happen to the 19:00  in `2005-07-15 17:00:00, 2005-07-17 18:00:00 , 2005-07-17 19:00:00 `

Comment: but fifference between `2005-07-17 23:00:00`  
`2005-07-18 00:00:00` is one hour, why not removed?

Comment: from this series: `pd.Timestamp('20170101') + pd.to_timedelta([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6.5, 7.5], unit='h')`, can you make clear which should be kept?

Comment: @jezrael any rows with *over* one hour difference should be removed.

Comment: @MaartenFabré Only 2017-01-01 05:00:00 should be removed.

Comment: Why not 6:30? That is more than 1h difference

Comment: To make things clearer: I work with 24 hours price data, recorded every hour. I then calculate the returns of those prices (np.log(data.close / data.close.shift(1))). 
Due to weekends, there are gap in the data. I want to remove the first row after such a gap. This will occur when the difference between the time of the current row and the time of the previous row is larger than 1 hour.

Comment: @MaartenFabré sorry, you are correct. 6:30 should be removed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) for difference and compare with `1 hour Timedelta`:

```
dates=['2005-07-15 17:00:00','2005-07-17 18:00:00', '2005-07-17 19:00:00',  
      '2005-07-17 23:00:00', '2005-07-18 00:00:00']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)}, index=pd.to_datetime(dates))

print (df)
                     a
2005-07-15 17:00:00  0
2005-07-17 18:00:00  1
2005-07-17 19:00:00  2
2005-07-17 23:00:00  3
2005-07-18 00:00:00  4
```

---

```
diff = df.index.to_series().diff().fillna(0)
print (diff)
2005-07-15 17:00:00   0 days 00:00:00
2005-07-17 18:00:00   2 days 01:00:00
2005-07-17 19:00:00   0 days 01:00:00
2005-07-17 23:00:00   0 days 04:00:00
2005-07-18 00:00:00   0 days 01:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

mask = diff <= pd.Timedelta(1, unit='h')
print (mask)
2005-07-15 17:00:00     True
2005-07-17 18:00:00    False
2005-07-17 19:00:00     True
2005-07-17 23:00:00    False
2005-07-18 00:00:00     True
dtype: bool

df = df[mask]
print (df)
                     a
2005-07-15 17:00:00  0
2005-07-17 19:00:00  2
2005-07-18 00:00:00  4
```